# Output XML opponent's name only, regardless of home or away

Tags: php, xml

I'm using PHP to output data from a sports XML file (in this example it's men's basketball). The XML file features home name ("hn") and visitor name ("vn"), for example the latest score's h3 is "Oregon State vs Stanford."

My question is, how can the h3 display only the opponent's name, regardless of whether they're home or away (in other words, it shouldn't say "Stanford", just the opponent's name, i.e. "Oregon State").

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/j2n0m4) and code:

```
    <?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.gostanford.com/data/xml/events/m-baskbl/2010/index.xml');

    // Reverse chronological order
    $xmlArray = array();
    foreach ($xml as $event_date) $xmlArray[] = $event_date;
    $xmlArray = array_reverse($xmlArray);

    foreach ($xmlArray as $event_date) {
        if(!empty($event_date->event['vn']) && !empty($event_date->event['hn']) && !empty($event_date->event['vs']) && !empty($event_date->event['hs']))
        {
                echo '<li>';
                    echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
                    echo '<p><strong>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' ', $event_date->event['vs'], ' - ', $event_date->event['hn'], ' ', $event_date->event['hs'], '</strong></p>';
                    echo '<p>', date('F j, Y', strtotime($event_date['date'])), '</p>';
                echo '</li>';
        }
    }   
    ?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Adam Kiss How can the h3 only display the opponent's name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 echo '<li>';
      echo '<h3>', $event_date->event['vn'], ' vs ', $event_date->event['hn'], '</h3>';
```

to

```
 $name = ($event_date->event['vc'] == 'stan') ? $event_date->event['hn'] : $event_date->event['vn'];
 echo '<li>';
      echo '<h3>', $name, '</h3>';
```